# ios how to add event in entity in Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, ibaction

I have an entity  'USer' and one attribute 'name'. I am trying to add one name to the entity 'User' using this code which is used in FirstViewController.m file:

```
- (IBAction)addUser:(id)sender {
    User *user = (User *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [user setName:@"Bhagwan"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}
```

But it is showing an error msg:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController addUser:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d38950'

how to solve this?
Please help!!

EDIT:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CoreDataTry2AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIViewController *_first; } @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *first;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext
*managedObjectContext; @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel
*managedObjectModel; @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
*persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

This is the App delegate file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing lies outside of the showed code. You are likely sending the addUser: message to a different object (one that does not implement it), or the object that implements the method is already deallocated (and it's memory reused for a different kind of object)

The button you are mentioning seems to have a UIViewController set as it's target and the addUser: selector as action. But UIViewController does not have a addUser: method you get an exception.

Make sure, that you connect the action of the button to an object that really implements an addUser: method.

Comment: I have a UIView class 'FirstViewController' in which I am using a round rect button and this button is connected to 'addUser' method.

Comment: i added the app delegate file to the question. first is the outlet as created by connecting the login controller in mainview.xib